# How to cancel model changes without using emberdata

Tags: ember.js

I have a screen where I can edit my 'Florida' model (this can be any state). How can I undo my changes to the model and transition back to Florida (I'm not currently using emberdata)?

If I simply do a transitionTo, the changes are still in my model.

This is what my url looks like:

http://localhost:4200/editor/state/florida/edit

Answer (score 0):

You have to roll it yourself. You need to track which fields are dirty, the previous values for those fields, and then provide a cancel/rollback method that you'll call on transition.

Comment: Would it be easier to pass a copy of the model and if they click cancel, just replace the model they were editing with the copy of the original?

Comment: If you were to use that approach, you'd need to keep 2 models for each edit.  If your models are large, that's an issue. Also if your models mixin Ember.Observable, I'm not sure what would happen to the other end of the observers as you swap out a model instance.  Generally, I would avoid this approach due to the complexity which it introduces.  It's far easier to just keep a dirty list with the original values.